# What is meant by "Path to MySQL bin" in the context of Wordpress for Google App Engine?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the [Quick Start Wordpress for Google App Engine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) guide. One of the instructions reads:

Using MySQL, run the following commands to set up your local database. Note that you will be prompted for your password and enter the MySQL shell after the fist command:

```
{PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN}/mysql -u root -p
create database wordpress_db;
exit;
```

I am not quite sure what location is meant by `PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN` in this context. I would expect it is where the MySQL files are stored, so following http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-datadir-files-stored-unix-linux/, I tried the `ps -eo cmd,args | grep mysql` command:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemoniz /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
sudo mysqld_safe --init-fil sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init
sudo mysql                  sudo mysql
mysql                       mysql
grep --color=auto mysql     grep --color=auto mysql
```

The results that show up do not appear to be directories. I also don't have a `var/lib/mysql` or `var/db/mysql` directory as mentioned on that site.

In short, how do I find the directory to perform the `create database wordpress_db` command in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the `PATH_TO_MYSQL_BIN`, if you are using a Linux instance. You just have to create the MySQL database. For that open a terminal and enter "mysql -u root -p" command to access the [MySQL console](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTJcgsM0df0).

Then you will be able to create databases using "create database wordpress_d" command.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/mysql -u root -p`